# Is there a way to scale an inline SVG from outside the <svg> tag?

Tags: css, vue.js, svg

I'm using a Ruby gem called [rqrcode](https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode) to generate a QR code as an SVG, and then sending it as an API response. In the frontend (Vue.js), I need to display the SVG at a specified size.

Right now my code looks like this, and while it does render the SVG, I can't specify the size.

```html
<div v-html="qrCode" />
```

I tried adding styles to the div, but the SVG disregards it completely. To give you an idea, this it what it looks like:

[image: div and svg]

My understanding is that you can scale SVGs using `width`, `height` and `viewBox` inside the `<svg>` tag.
However, there's no way to specify those properties in rqrcode - the height and width are decided by the gem, and the opening svg tag looks like this:

`<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="246" height="246" shape-rendering="crispEdges">`

So my question is, how can I specify the size of the inline SVG to fit inside the parent container, from the parent container?

**[Edit for clarification]** If the dimensions in the `<svg>` tag are larger than my div container, I'd like for the svg to shrink to fit the container.
And vice versa - if the dimensions are smaller, I want the svg to expand ot fit the container. I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: For the div, change position to relative...specify height and width in the div stylings

Comment: And for the svg class set height and width as 100%

Comment: instead of  `width="246" height="246"` use `viewBox="0 0 246 246"`

Comment: @enxaneta As I wrote in the question, I can't set `width`, `height`, or `viewBox`, because everything inside the `<svg>` tag is auto-generated by the rqrcode gem. My question is whether you can scale the SVG from its parent container.

Comment: Then use javascript to get rid of that ``width`` and ``height`` and set a ``viewBox``, as enxaneta says, that is the root cause of your problem

Comment: @reesaspieces I doubt you are still working on this, but if you are check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually override the inline `height` and `width` using css.

Note that the css needs to be NOT scoped, so create another style block if required.

```html
<style scoped>
  ...
</style>
<style>
div > svg {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and it's halfway there - the SVG element now has the specified height and width. Problem is, it's not scaling. As in, if the `width` and `height` in the `<svg>` tag are `200px`, and I specify `100px` in CSS like your code above, it only shows the top left corner of the SVG. Any ideas?

Comment: @camaulay Thanks, I think this solution didn't work because the SVG's internals also had fixed widths/heights, but otherwise yours would've worked. I'm accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add position as relative and set width to the svg class. Do not forget to give a classname to the svg. Here I have assumed the class name to be 'svgClass'

```
div {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
  position: relative; /* add this line! */
}

svg {  /* class name of the svg */
  width:100% !important;
  height:100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way for me to add a class to the SVG, because I'm using the SVG code received from the API. Please let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: Doesn't matter ....jus give the stylings as svg {} itself...please check my edited answer

Comment: Added `position: relative;` to the `div` container and `max-width:100%;` to `svg`, but this causes the same problem as the other solution - the SVG gets cut off instead of shrinking if it's larger than the dimensions of the div. Ideally, I want the svg to shrink to the size of the div, or grow if it's not big enough.

Comment: I have added !important...check my edited answer

Comment: Same result, the SVG gets truncated instead of shrinking to fit the size of the container :/

Comment: Can you add a snap of it?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: TLDR: The as_svg method on the qr class supports a module_size option, change it to something smaller, the default is 11.

I'm dealing with the same exact problem right now.  If you inspect the html element that is the svg, you obviously see that it has height and width specified by the gem that created it, in my case it's 495x495.  When I change these in the inspector I get the same thing as you, it adjusts to the specified height and width, but it's just cutting off most of the qr code. Upon further inspection of my QR SVG I have 1030 child rect elements each with it's own specified height, width, x and y values.

[image]

I was about to go down a path of maybe looping over all of these children and scaling it down but I just found some things that I missed in the docs the first time I did this.

You can change the module size, for me changing the module_size to 5 gives me an svg that is 225x225

From the repo here https://github.com/whomwah/rqrcode

```
qrcode = RQRCode::QRCode.new("http://github.com/")

# NOTE: showing with default options specified explicitly
svg = qrcode.as_svg(
  color: "000",
  shape_rendering: "crispEdges",
  module_size: 11,
  standalone: true,
  use_path: true
)
```